# Store SQL query result (1 column) as Array

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

After running my query I get 1 column result as

```
5
6
98
101
```

Is there a way to store this result as array so that I can use it later 
in queries like

```
WHERE NOT IN ('5','6','98','101')
```

I am aware of storing single variable results but is this possible?

I can not use @Table variable as I will be rerunning the query again in the future and it goes out of scope

Comment: One quick workaround to store as XML somewhere, then `WHERE NOT IN (SELECT t.c.value('...', 'type') as name FROM  somewhere.column.nodes(tc)` to parse it

Comment: is it a single field with a multiline value? or does the query return multiple rows?

Comment: Agree with using XML.  Either way you're going to do a Split string and a Stuff, which rely on XML anyway. so why not skip a step and just use the raw XML

Comment: Gosh this is pretty much the same thing as your previous question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570162/can-table-variables-stored-in-the-past-in-sql-server When you need this data between executions, that happen monthly, you need to put this data in a table.

Comment: You can store values as `csv`s in `mysql` this would help you achieve the result. Simply set the `type` to `string` and have the data persisted as a csv

Comment: @DanHabib I am sorry but I am using SQL Server. Any way??

Comment: @user2961712 You can store `csv` values in a column in `sql`

Comment: @DanHabib  Do you have a small code sample explaining this please? I would truly like to use your method but I am unable to find more information online about it

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple way of storing those column data like using `Temporary Tables` or `View` or `Table valued function` but IMO there is no need of storing that column data anywhere. You can directly use that column in any query saying below (or) perform a `JOIN` which would be much better option than `NOT IN`

```
select * from 
table2
where some_column not in (select column1 from this_table);
```

Comment: Won't really work for what he's trying to do http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32570162/can-table-variables-stored-in-the-past-in-sql-server

Comment: As I actually plan to store my array for later use after a certain period of time.       In your code  table2 is just a more recent version of this_table. Therefore it wont work

Answer (score 0):

While this method is **not** recommended, storing an array in a single column can be done using `CSV`'s(Comma Separated Values). Simply create a `VARCHAR` array and store it by storing a string containing the values in a specific order. Basically store all of your values into a string with each value being separated by a `comma` in that string. Store that into a column of your choice. You can later fetch the string and parse it with a string parser i.e using the `.split()` function in python. **AGAIN** I do not recommend doing this, I would instead use multiple columns, one referring to each value and access them that way instead
Using separate columns would make it easy to use in a `Stored Procedure`.

Comment: thank you but do you have an example I can refer to? This is bit complicated and I am not able to find information online